# An integral inequality $\frac1{b-a} \int_a^b e^{f(x)}dx\ge e^{\frac1{b-a} \int_a^bf(x)dx}$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$

Prove:$$\frac1{b-a} \int_a^b e^{f(x)}dx\ge e^{\frac1{b-a} \int_a^bf(x)dx}(*)$$

Here is my current work:

$\text{let}$ $A=\int_a^bf(x)dx$ and $B=b-a$ use the ineuqality $e^x \ge1+x $

$(*)$ $<=>$ $\int_a^b e^{f(x)}dx \ge A+B$

I want to prove for all $A\in R$ and $B>0$ we have $A+B\ge Be^{\frac{A}{B}}$

I try to fixed $B$ and let $g(A)=A+B-Be^{\frac{A}{B}}$ and $G(0)=0$

But $g'(A)=1-e^{\frac{A}{B}}$ when $A>0$ the function is monotone decreasing

I think the reason is the inequality I zooming too far?

Can anyone help me ? thanks

Comment: You say that you "want to prove for all $A\in R$ and $B>0$ we have $A+B\ge Be^{\frac{A}{B}}$", but with $A= B = 1$ you get $2 \ge e$ which is obviously not true.

Answer (score 2):

This is just Jensen's inequality for integrals taking $ \phi(x) = e^x$ which is clearly convex and taking the measure $ \mu = \lambda/(b-a) $ where $\lambda $ is the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R} $. Just apply
$$ \phi(\int^b_a f d\mu ) \leq \int^b_a (\phi\circ f) d\mu $$ 
This gives your required result.

Comment: I just learn the basic analysis and can you explain it or use an fundamental way?

Comment: @Xiaolang I think you have to use the convexity of $e^x$ somewhere, maybe you can try along with integral mean value theorem. You can also look up the proof of Jensen in any standard textbook which is not very hard.